# Travis CI Deploy to AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, travis-ci

**Hi I currently try to deploy my react app to AWS Elastic Bean Stalk through travis CI. But it fail.. what should I change in my travis yml??**

Here is my .travis.yml

```
sudo: required
services:
  - docker
before_install:
  - docker build -t sample:dev .

script:
  - docker run -e CI=true sample:dev npm run test -- --coverage

deploy:
  provider: elasticbeanstalk
  region: "us-west-1"
  app: "my-app"
  env: "MyApp-env"
  bucket_name: "xxxx"
  bucket_path: "xxx"
  on:
    branch: master
  access_key_id: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY
  secret_access_key:
    secure: "$AWS_SECRET_KEY"
```

**But I failed to deploy it in aws elastic bean stalk. Here is the message from travis ci:**

The command "docker run -e CI=true sample:dev npm run test -- --coverage" exited with 0.
dpl_0
1.27s$ rvm $(travis_internal_ruby) --fuzzy do ruby -S gem install dpl
dpl.1
Installing deploy dependencies
Successfully installed jmespath-1.4.0
Successfully installed aws-eventstream-1.0.3
Successfully installed aws-sigv4-1.1.1
NEWER VERSION AVAILABLE: Please upgrade to AWS SDK For Ruby V3
Successfully installed aws-sdk-core-2.11.471
NEWER VERSION AVAILABLE: Please upgrade to AWS SDK For Ruby V3
Successfully installed aws-sdk-resources-2.11.471
NEWER VERSION AVAILABLE: Please upgrade to AWS SDK For Ruby V3
Successfully installed aws-sdk-2.11.471
Successfully installed rubyzip-1.3.0
Successfully installed dpl-elastic_beanstalk-1.10.15
8 gems installed
!!! AWS Elastic Beanstalk support is experimental !!!
dpl.2
Preparing deploy
Cleaning up git repository with `git stash --all`. If you need build artifacts for deployment, set `deploy.skip_cleanup: true`. See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment#Uploading-Files-and-skip_cleanup.
No local changes to save
NEWER VERSION AVAILABLE: Please upgrade to AWS SDK For Ruby V3
dpl.3
Deploying application
No stash entries found.
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.471/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:15:in `call': The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Aws::S3::Errors::SignatureDoesNotMatch)
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.471/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/s3_sse_cpk.rb:19:in`call'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.471/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/s3_dualstack.rb:24:in `call'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.471/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/s3_accelerate.rb:34:in`call'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.471/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/jsonvalue_converter.rb:20:in `call'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.471/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/idempotency_token.rb:18:in`call'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.471/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_converter.rb:20:in `call'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.471/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:21:in`call'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.471/lib/seahorse/client/request.rb:70:in `send_request'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.471/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:207:in`block (2 levels) in define_operation_methods'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-resources-2.11.471/lib/aws-sdk-resources/request.rb:24:in `call'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-resources-2.11.471/lib/aws-sdk-resources/operations.rb:41:in`call'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/aws-sdk-resources-2.11.471/lib/aws-sdk-resources/operation_methods.rb:19:in `block in add_operation'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/dpl-elastic_beanstalk-1.10.15/lib/dpl/provider/elastic_beanstalk.rb:131:in`upload'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/dpl-elastic_beanstalk-1.10.15/lib/dpl/provider/elastic_beanstalk.rb:49:in `push_app'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/dpl-1.10.15/lib/dpl/provider.rb:199:in`block in deploy'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/dpl-1.10.15/lib/dpl/cli.rb:41:in `fold'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/dpl-1.10.15/lib/dpl/provider.rb:199:in`deploy'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/dpl-1.10.15/lib/dpl/cli.rb:32:in `run'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/dpl-1.10.15/lib/dpl/cli.rb:7:in`run'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/dpl-1.10.15/bin/dpl:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/bin/dpl:23:in`load'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/bin/dpl:23:in `'
failed to deploy

Answer (score 1):

Based on the new version of Travis CI, following lines code, you need to update

`secret_access_key:
        secure: "$AWS_SECRET_KEY"`

Change it to :
   `secret_access_key: "$AWS_SECRET_KEY"`

Alse need to add "skip_cleanup: true" under deploy:

Because Travis CI now consider default variable as secure.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the first error from your output:

`call': The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Aws::S3::Errors::SignatureDoesNotMatch)`

I got the same error and it was caused by a mismatch on the `access_key_id` and `secret_access_key`. I resolved it by running:

`travis encrypt --add deploy.access_key_id <access_key_id>`

`travis encrypt --add deploy.secret_access_key <secret_access_key>`